# UDP Packet drops

Tags: networking, proc, udp

I understand that the receive flow for a UDP packet is

1. Check udp header for errors
2. Match destination to socket
3. Send an error message back if no such socket
4. Put packet into appropriate socket receive queue
5. Wake up process waiting for data for that socket

But in the above stages what would `/proc/net/udp` count as a drop? Does the failure of any step above constitute as a drop? Or is it only when the receive queue/buffer is full?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux 5.4.66, the pseudo-file `/proc/net/udp` is generated by a function in [`net/ipv4/udp.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.66/source/net/ipv4/udp.c%5D):

```c
int udp4_seq_show(struct seq_file *seq, void *v)
{
        seq_setwidth(seq, 127);
        if (v == SEQ_START_TOKEN)
                seq_puts(seq, "  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue "
                           "rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout "
                           "inode ref pointer drops");
        else {
                struct udp_iter_state *state = seq->private;

                udp4_format_sock(v, seq, state->bucket);
        }
        seq_pad(seq, '\n');
        return 0;
}
```

That calls `udp4_format_sock()` in the same file:

```c
static void udp4_format_sock(struct sock *sp, struct seq_file *f,
                int bucket)
{
        struct inet_sock *inet = inet_sk(sp);
        __be32 dest = inet->inet_daddr;
        __be32 src  = inet->inet_rcv_saddr;
        __u16 destp       = ntohs(inet->inet_dport);
        __u16 srcp        = ntohs(inet->inet_sport);

        seq_printf(f, "%5d: %08X:%04X %08X:%04X"
                " %02X %08X:%08X %02X:%08lX %08X %5u %8d %lu %d %pK %u",
                bucket, src, srcp, dest, destp, sp->sk_state,
                sk_wmem_alloc_get(sp),
                udp_rqueue_get(sp),
                0, 0L, 0,
                from_kuid_munged(seq_user_ns(f), sock_i_uid(sp)),
                0, sock_i_ino(sp),
                refcount_read(&sp->sk_refcnt), sp,
                atomic_read(&sp->sk_drops));
}
```

Note that the value of the `drops` field comes from `atomic_read(&sp->sk_drops)`.  That value is incremented using `atomic_inc(&sk->sk_drops)` in a couple of places.

1. The receive queue is full

   ```c
   int __udp_enqueue_schedule_skb(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)
   {
            ...
           /* try to avoid the costly atomic add/sub pair when the receive
            * queue is full; always allow at least a packet
            */
           rmem = atomic_read(&sk->sk_rmem_alloc);
           if (rmem > sk->sk_rcvbuf)
                    goto drop;
          ...
   drop:
           atomic_inc(&sk->sk_drops);
   ```
2. Bad checksum frames

   ```c
   static struct sk_buff *__first_packet_length(struct sock *sk,
                                                struct sk_buff_head *rcvq,
                                                int *total)
   {
           struct sk_buff *skb;

           while ((skb = skb_peek(rcvq)) != NULL) {
                   if (udp_lib_checksum_complete(skb)) {
                           ...
                           atomic_inc(&sk->sk_drops);
   ```
3. Failure to read

   ```c
   int udp_recvmsg(struct sock *sk, struct msghdr *msg, size_t len, int noblock,
                   int flags, int *addr_len)
   {
           ...
           if (checksum_valid || udp_skb_csum_unnecessary(skb)) {
                   if (udp_skb_is_linear(skb))
                           err = copy_linear_skb(skb, copied, off, &msg->msg_iter);
                   else
                           err = skb_copy_datagram_msg(skb, off, msg, copied);
           } else {
                   err = skb_copy_and_csum_datagram_msg(skb, off, msg);

                   if (err == -EINVAL)
                           goto csum_copy_err;
           }

           if (unlikely(err)) {
                   if (!peeking) {
                           atomic_inc(&sk->sk_drops);
   ```
4. Failures during receive

   ```c
   static int udp_queue_rcv_one_skb(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)
   {
           ...
   drop:
           ...
           atomic_inc(&sk->sk_drops);
   ```
5. Failures during multicast processing when trying to clone the message

   ```c
   static int __udp4_lib_mcast_deliver(struct net *net, struct sk_buff *skb,
                                       struct udphdr  *uh,
                                       __be32 saddr, __be32 daddr,
                                       struct udp_table *udptable,
                                       int proto)
   {
           ...
           sk_for_each_entry_offset_rcu(sk, node, &hslot->head, offset) {
                   ...
                   nskb = skb_clone(skb, GFP_ATOMIC);

                   if (unlikely(!nskb)) {
                           atomic_inc(&sk->sk_drops);
   ```

Comment: Great answer thank you :)